Event Bridge Pattern Matching Key
I am trying to integrate commercetools via event bridge, I receive events like this:
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "...",
    "detail-type": "StoreProductSelectionsChanged",
    "source": "...",
    "account": "...",
    "time": "2024-05-23T15:57:19Z",
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "notificationType": "Message",
        "projectKey": "...",
        "id": "...",
        "version": 1,
        "sequenceNumber": 19,
        "resource": {
            "typeId": "store",
            "id": "..."
        },
        "resourceVersion": 19,
        "resourceUserProvidedIdentifiers": {
            "key": "test"
        },
        "type": "StoreProductSelectionsChanged",
        "updatedProductSelections": [
            {
                "productSelection": {
                    "typeId": "product-selection",
                    "id": "..."
                },
                "active": false
            }
        ]
    }
}

The key in the event can be updatedProductSelections (like in the example), addedProductSelections or removedProductSelections.
I am trying to match all three separatly.
The pattern i tried were either content-matching or like this:
{
  "detail-type": [
    "StoreProductSelectionsChanged"
  ],
  "source": [{
    "prefix": "aws.partner/commercetools.com"
  }],
  "detail": {
    "updatedProductSelections": [{
      "wildcard": "*"
    }]
  }
}

But this does not work. I searched a lot and red the docs, but no fitting answer...
Does any one have a solution?
